# How to interact with MongoDB via shell in OpenShift Online 3 Dev Preview?

Tags: mongodb, openshift, openshift-nextgen

I've got multiple issues with an application which I suspect are related to permissions on the database.

Everything seems locked down however and I can't complete basic commands such as `show dbs` in order to troubleshoot the problems further and "see" what I'm working with. I've been stuck on this for two days now and it's really frustrating.

I've tried this both from the online console and on local terminal, both with and without user credentials supplied at login:

**Online Console**

`Console` > `MongoDB Service` > `Deployment` > `Pod` > `mongodb-1-vs19d` > `Terminal`:

```
sh-4.2$ mongo                                                                   
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.9                                                    
connecting to: test                                                             
> show dbs                                                                      
2016-07-13T04:33:10.809-0400 listDatabases failed:{                             
        "ok" : 0,                                                               
        "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { listDatabases: 
1.0 }",                                                                         
        "code" : 13                                                             
} at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:47
```

**Local Terminal**

```
me@my-computer:~$ oc rsh mongodb-1-vs19d
sh-4.2$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.9
connecting to: test
> show dbs
2016-07-13T04:35:06.449-0400 listDatabases failed:{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { listDatabases: 1.0 }",
    "code" : 13
} at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:47
```

**Local Terminal With User Credentials**

```
me@my-computer:~$ oc rsh mongodb-1-vs19d
sh-4.2$ mongo -u $MONGODB_USER -p $MONGODB_PASSWORD $MONGODB_DATABASE
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.9
connecting to: users
> show dbs
2016-07-13T04:51:39.127-0400 listDatabases failed:{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { listDatabases: 1.0 }",
    "code" : 13
} at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:47
```

Troubleshooting `envars` are correct:

```
me@my-computer:~$ oc env pods mongodb-1-vs19d --list
# pods mongodb-1-vs19d, container mongodb
MONGODB_USER=admin
MONGODB_PASSWORD=secret
MONGODB_DATABASE=users
MONGODB_ADMIN_PASSWORD=very-secret
```

The database was created from local terminal with:

```
oc new-app mongodb-persistent -p MONGODB_USER=admin,MONGODB_PASSWORD=secret,MONGODB_ADMIN_PASSWORD=very-secret
```

As per official docs:

https://docs.openshift.com/online/getting_started/beyond_the_basics.html#btb-provisioning-a-database

https://docs.openshift.com/online/using_images/db_images/mongodb.html#running-mongodb-commands-in-containers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to `show dbs` as user who has not been granted the needed role. You can try authenticating yourself as `admin` as follows:

```
mongo -u admin -p $MONGODB_ADMIN_PASSWORD admin
```

Then you should be able to `show dbs`, `show users`, `use` other databases and show users there, etc...

---

It's a bit confusing that your `$MONGODB_USER` is named `admin` - this regular user will have access to the `$MONGODB_DATABASE`. Another `admin` [has been created by the used image](https://docs.openshift.com/online/using_images/db_images/mongodb.html#environment-variables) most likely as well.

Comment: Using the login statement you provided allows me to login from local terminal and `show dbs`, which is great.   In regards to why `$MONGODB_USER` is named `admin` - the docs say to set the database up like this:  `$ oc new-app mongodb-persistent -p MONGODB_USER=admin,MONGODB_PASSWORD=secret,MONGODB_ADMIN_PASSWORD=super-secret` .  See:  https://docs.openshift.com/online/getting_started/beyond_the_basics.html#btb-provisioning-a-database  I'd appreciate any clarification around what steps should be taken.  Also, what username and password should the application use to login?  admin or ?